# CSS resize property both doesn't work properly with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using the CSS resize property with flexbox, and it only works vertically and not horizontally. The second problem is the 
vertical behavior let you resize just a little bit.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.box {
 flex: 1 1 50%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 4em;
 resize: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
 <div class="box">1</div>
 <div class="box">2</div>
 <div class="box">3</div>
 <div class="box">4</div>
</section>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think your problem is coming from `padding: 4em;` and from `flex: 1 1 50%;`

Comment: You can't make this effect "clean" without using JavaScript along with your CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it could help:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.box {
 width: 50%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100px;
 resize: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
 <div class="box">1</div>
 <div class="box">2</div>
 <div class="box">3</div>
 <div class="box">4</div>
</section>
```